# Changing URL of single route in resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have

```
resources :users, only: %i[new create edit update]
```

I would like to change typical `/users/new` to `/signup`.
Code like below is ugly.

```
resources :users, only: %i[create edit update]
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
```

Is there a better (cleaner) way to do it?

EDIT: Seems like it's the best way that there is. Guess grouping is the only way to keep it readable.

Comment: what is "ugly" about that? How would you imagine it working to be less "ugly"?

Comment: What do you think this question is about? I am asking if there is a better way to do it (doesn't have to be). Imho when I am reading `resources` I expect there is every route used in here. In this case one route is seperated from the main group which leads to worse readability. That's why it's ugly.

Comment: Your proposed solution is readable, easy and clear. Not ugly. Is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the best you're going to be able to do is

```
resources :users, only: [:new], path_names: { new: "sign_up" }, path: '/'
resources :users, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
```

which at least makes it easier to tell that 'sign_up' is part of the users resource. If you're fine with `/users/sign_up` you can do it in one line, but wanting to get rid of the `/users` part makes this trickier.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep them organized and do not mind the route being "/users/signup" then this will work.

```
resources :users, only: %i[create edit update] do 
  get 'signup', to: :new, on: :collection, as: :signup
end
```

Then `rake routes`

```
          signup_users GET      /users/signup(.:format)         users#new
                 users POST     /users(.:format)                users#create
            edit_users GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
                 users PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                       PUT      /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
```

Comment: I do mind, that's the whole point to keep it short. Default "users/new" would be better then this.

Comment: @Kappa your aggression is so refreshing. I always think to myself hmmm I really hope the person I am trying to help is extraordinarily truculent.